# Learning Mongodb and having a simple issue with MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb-query

I have the following C# code as I'm learning MongoDB but I get the following error even though this code is straight out of the mongodb documentation!  Is there something I'm doing wrong?

The error in visual studio hightlights the "filter" on the last line.

Thanks,

**Compiler error**

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'MongoDB.Driver.FilterDefinition<MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument>' to 'MongoDB.Driver.IMongoQuery
```

**Code snippet**

```
var id = 123921;
var collection = ...GetCollection<CustomerEntity>("Customer");
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("Customer", id);

var result = await collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your problem lies in way of saving your objects. You saved them as MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument but try to get as CustomerEntity. Due to impossibility to convert from BsonDocument to CustomerEntity you receive this error message. [Here](https://blog.zaletskyy.com/post/2016/03/01/post100) I described how you can have CRUD operations in mongodb version 2

Comment: The link is not available.

Comment: @Javad-M fixed link